# WP REST API format response

Tags: json, rest-api

I'm using 'WP REST API Version 2.0-beta12" by http://wp-api.org/ to use REST API, available via HTTP of my site's data in simple JSON format.
I have formatted my json output to limit reponse field while list post API - http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts using rest_prepare_post as follows,

```
function api_remove_extra_data( $data, $post, $context ) {
    // We only want to modify the 'view' context, for reading posts
    if ( $context !== 'view' || is_wp_error( $data ) ) {
        // Here, we unset any data we don't want to see on the front end:
        unset ( $data->data ['link']); 
        unset ( $data->data ['date_gmt']);
        unset ( $data->data ['modified']);
        unset ( $data->data ['modified_gmt']);
        unset ( $data->data ['type']);
        unset ( $data->data ['content']);
        unset ( $data->data ['excerpt']);
        unset ( $data->data ['author']);
        // continue unsetting whatever other fields you want
        return $data;
    }

}

add_filter( 'rest_prepare_post', 'api_remove_extra_data', 12, 3 );
```

It works great. But I need full post data in single post API call such as

http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/1077

```
Wordpress version:  4.4.2

Plugin Version : WP REST API 2.0-beta12
```

By using above filter both posts list API and view single post API return only limited response. How can I get all post data in post single (http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/1077) API by keeping limited response in posts list API?

Answer (score 3):

Since you're filtering with the `rest_prepare_{post_type}` filter, you could restrict it to the `WP_REST_Posts_Controller::get_items()` callback, with the `rest_{post_type}_query` filter:

```
add_filter( 'rest_post_query', function( $args )
{
    add_filter( 'rest_prepare_post', 'api_remove_extra_data', 12, 3 );
    return $args;
} );
```

where the post type is `post`.

Note that in general we always want to return the filter value and I don't follow the logic your `api_remove_extra_data()` callback. Maybe it's a relic from version 1.x?

This is how the filter is now defined in version 2:

```
/**
 * Filter the post data for a response.
 *
 * The dynamic portion of the hook name, $this->post_type, refers to post_type of the post
 * being prepared for the response.
 *
 * @param WP_REST_Response   $response   The response object.
 * @param WP_Post            $post       Post object.
 * @param WP_REST_Request    $request    Request object.
*/
return apply_filters( "rest_prepare_{$this->post_type}", $response, $post, $request );
```